# Should each module (in a multi-module Maven project) have its own dedicated Exception?

Tags: java, exception

We have a multi-module Maven project where each module has its own associated exception. For example, tree-service-module would have TreeServiceException, user-service-module would have UserServiceException, and login-service-module would have LoginServiceException.

Each of these three  modules has a main Service class: TreeService, UserService, and LoginService. Every method in TreeService throws TreeServiceException, every method in UserService throws UserServiceException, and every method in LoginService throws LoginServiceException. We handle these exceptions by logging them and throwing them up the call hierarchy.

Is this a good design? At first glance, it seems to me like these exceptions are not useful. Instead, they produce unnecessary code. Furthermore, they take the place of useful exceptions, which will be ignored in favor of these not useful exceptions. It's standard practice for a method to throw no more than one exception, in which case we are filling that slot with an exception that is not useful. Lastly, I'm not sure if it's helpful to have every method in a class conform to throwing the same exception.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: In the light of exception experience, and emergence of FP, I would be leaving exceptions totally out of the picture. In reality, I don't remember where my code was doing `throw MyException` or event `throw Exception` at all. Consider user of these services, they are supposed to isolate user from all possible bad-goings within them. So what is the point of throwing exceptions? Your service either success or failing, that should be its return. Then service logs whatever goes wrong, and catches all necessary exception from outer world.

Comment: Put it that way, if outer world is throwing exception, and your services are reflecting those exceptions by increasing complexity (because you are inevitably adding it with additional abstraction layer), what is the point of having services if they are supposed to make user's life easier.

Comment: Of course, there are bad exceptions like, OOM, Interrupted etc. But catching those, or reacting to them is meaningless, and normally harmful.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this question is primarily opinion-based. However, I'd opt to **not** use three different classes.

My main argument is that you could use some other subclass of `Exception` or `RuntimeException` (that better fits the reason for why the exception is being thrown) and take advantage of the `message` parameter that the class' constructor accepts (optionally).

With this `message` parameter, you can specify exactly which module the exception was thrown in (if needed, seeing as the stacktrace will already tell you where it was thrown from) along with any other helpful information regarding the current state of the program.

Comment: So you would rather not use a dedicated exception for each module?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, but I would **not** use a dedicated exception for each module. I would, instead, use the correct subclass that pertains to the current state of the program (`IllegalArgumentException`, `IllegalStateException`, etc.)